# inline expression ASP.Net in ascx file

Tags: asp.net, inline

I'm trying to access variables which are declared in resource file named AspSPSSiLog.resx .

```
<asp:Literal ID="LiteralCurrentSimu" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:AspSPSSiLog,current_simulation_title%>" />
```

When i Run the code, i have a HttpParserException => The resource object with key 'current_simulation_title' was not found.

I think that the inline expression mentioned above means search for the object current_simulation_title in AspSPSSiLog resource file in the Resources Folder right ?

Could any one have an idea about that give me a hand.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here your resource file: `AspSPSSiLog.resx` will be treated as Global resource file.

And therefore, Asp.Net searches for the ResourceID:  `current_simulation_title` in `AspSPSSiLog.resx` resource file inside `App_GlobalResources` folder present in root of your application.

So, firstly create a folder named: `App_GlobalResources` in root of your application and then  place your resource file: `AspSPSSiLog.resx` inside this folder.

Comment: Exactly, that's the correct Answer, the resource file was not copied inside App_GlobalResources folder.